# Angular2 RC5 input pattern binding not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular

I'm having trouble with regular expressions in Angular2 RC5. If I hard code the regex (like below), everything works perfectly.

```
<input type="text" 
       name="date"
       class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="date" 
       placeholder="e.g. 24/05/2016" 
       (change)="updateAvailability()" 
       pattern="^(11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26)\/(8|08)\/(2016)$"
       title="Date Format (DD/MM/YYYY)"
       required />
```

However, the pattern is being build dynamically as part of the component, so when I try to bind to the pattern attribute (as below), the validation no longer works.

```
<input type="text" 
       name="date"
       class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="date" 
       placeholder="e.g. 24/05/2016" 
       (change)="updateAvailability()" 
       [pattern]="datePattern"
       title="Date Format (DD/MM/YYYY)"
       required />
```

I've tried using interpolation e.g.

```
pattern="{{ datePattern }}"
```

but that produces the exact same results.

When I look at the DOM using Developer Tools in the browser, everything appears to be correct, but Angular seems to be adding an **ng-reflect-pattern** (see below) attribute with the exact same value. I can't find any documentation on this anywhere, and not sure if this is related to the problem or not.

```
<input name="date" 
       title="Date Format (DD/MM/YYYY)" 
       class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" 
       required="" 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="e.g. 24/05/2016" 
       pattern="^(11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26)\/(8|08)\/(2016)$" 
       _ngcontent-abf-3="" 
       ng-reflect-name="date" 
       ng-reflect-pattern="^(11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26)\/(8|08)\/(2016)$"
       ng-reflect-model=""></input>
```

I can't understand why the pattern attribute can be identical in the DOM, but hard coding the pattern works, and binding to the component doesn't.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated?

Cheers.